# Unintuitive Behavior of NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate * thePredicate1= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm];
```

If searchterm is an empty string a search using thePredicate1 should return all right?

Wrong.

If it's nil it'll return an error.

My problem is I have to create a special case. So if Title is empty (or nil) then I will have to create a predicate that always return true. Because CONTAINS "" always return false.

I think Contains @"" should always return true. Every string contain an empty string

What's their consideration when they have this issue?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you pass an empty string or `nil`? They're different things.

Comment: If I pass nil, I got an error. If I pass an empty string I got 0 results which also doesn't make sense. Every string contains an empty string right?

Comment: Hi Jim. I have the same issue.
When you come from other languages like C# , Java,..  it is normal to think like you.
i am also expecting that a predicate filter of empty string must match all strings.

So ! What is the result ?
Could you find anything ?

I am trying to filter an array of strings and i am expecting it to return the whole array back when i send an empty string as a predicate filter string. 

Must
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTerm]
return values or not. Help please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@", @""]);
NSLog(@"%@", [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@", nil]);
```

Logs:

```
2011-06-18 17:53:44.037 EmptyFoundation[11247:903] Title CONTAINS[cd] ""
2011-06-18 17:53:44.040 EmptyFoundation[11247:903] Title CONTAINS[cd] nil
```

What's your problem again?  Is `searchTerm` not an object?

Comment: So it's okay to ask for @"" but not for Nil?

Comment: @Jim you can use `nil` in a predicate just fine.  For example `title == nil` would be the predicate to find all objects where the `title` property is unset (not just an empty string).  I'm not sure what `title contains nil` would do, though.

Comment: exception. Also title contains "" always return false I think because my table becomes empty

Answer (score 1):

Note that the documentation for a similar method, `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, contains the following warning:

> **Important:** Raises an
>   NSInvalidArgumentException if format
>   is nil.